# Multi-threading model concept

Tags: multithreading, operating-system

I was reading the dinosaur book on Operating systems , and I have a doubt about the multithreading model.

---

line 1: User threads are supported above the kernel and are managed without kernel support.

line 2:The many-to-one model  maps many user-level threads to one kernel thread

my question is , what's the need of mapping user level thread and kernel level thread?

Comment: I answered a similar question not too long ago, see if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65166394/10678955.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question completely. In modern OSes running on x86 CPUs there is no real kernel threads. Operating systems are mostly interrupt driven.

For example on Linux you have systemd which runs as the first process of the kernel. Then systemd looks at its "units" which are configuration files which allow to specify what is going to run next. This is responsible to show you the famous user GUI interface. So you have a target file which specifies several units which should run at the system startup.

At boot the kernel will initialize lots of stuff and then will start systemd. The systemd process is itself a user mode process which will look on the file system in predefined directories for units files. It will then run what is specified in the units files. Since systemd is a user mode process then all processes running are user mode processes.

How it works is that the kernel will setup handlers for timer interrupts. It will start the timer and the timer will count down to 0. The timer will then raise an interrupt which will launch an handler. That handler will call schedule() in the kernel. The schedule function will determine what process to run next and reschedule the timer.

There cannot be user threads running on top of one kernel thread that would require having a kernel thread always running. This is impossible especially on systems with only one core.

When you launch an executable, the GUI interface or command line you are using is making system calls in kernel code it has been linked against during compilation or dynamically before launch. The system call uses sysenter special x86 instruction to jump to an address specified in a special register. This register cannot be set after boot. This is providing security so that user mode processes cannot change what instructions will run when making a system call using `int 0x80`. Once in kernel mode, the code has access to all hardware and all instructions.

What we achieve by doing this is security. Because the user mode process cannot just decide to destroy the system or run any kernel code it wants. If the user mode process tries to run kernel code it is limited by the sysenter instruction which provides a software interface to run kernel code from user mode. Even though a malicious user mode code can do a lot of harm, it cannot run any kernel code.

This separation between user mode code and kernel mode code is done at different levels. You can specify the access level on a page to page basis setting certain bits in the page tables. You can specify the access level of interrupts as well by setting certain bits in the IDT. All of this is done at boot by the OS.